# Ionic5 prod build error - unknown component

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

My issue with `ionic capacitor build --prod ios` is that my working components starting with the likes of

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
```

fail build with

```
'ion-grid' is not a known element:
1. If 'ion-grid' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ion-grid' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENT
```

Without the `--prod` it works fine. However, without the `--prod` I am not able to sucessfully run

```
    import { Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

    ...

    try{
        enableProdMode();
    }catch{
        this.logger.logError('Prod Mode Failed');
    }
```

I managed to get `--prod` to build with setting `aot` and `buildOptimizer` in `angular.json` to false

```
              "aot": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
```

However, this seems to make the `--prod` irrelevant? At least `enableProdMode` is still failing... ?

Adding `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` like proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107798/error-message-while-trying-to-build-ionic-app) has not made any difference either.

Comment: import your components in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by importing `IonicModule` into my component moduels. The boilerplate code from the `ionic generate` does not include this.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```